# Using LINQ with dynamic variables in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dynamic-keyword

Is this the right way to use dynamic variables in C#?

I am getting the below error when i try to use LINQ expressions with dynamic variable..

**Error - Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic dAnimal = new Animal();
            string cc = dAnimal.x;
            Animal oAnimal = new Animal();
            var test1 = oAnimal.listFood.Where(a => a.foodName == "");
            var test2 = dAnimal.listFood.Where(a => a.foodName == "");//Error
        }
    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public string animalName {get; set;};
        public List<Food> listFood;
    }

    public class Food
    {
        public string foodName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you could just cast dAnimal.listFood to IEnumerable<Food>

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the problem is that `dAnimal.listFood` type is unknown at compilation time, because `dAnimal` is dynamic. So compiler can't guarantee, that `listFood` is IEnumerable and it's item has `foodName` property. However, if you will use delegate, every `listFood` item will implicitly be casted to type of delegate input parameter (you will still have a problem with collection type).

Any way, there is no any need to use `dynamic` in this context.